# Laravel 4.2 Composer install error: Could not scan for classes inside "app/models"

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

In my Laravel 4.2 project I have moved my User model to a new directory within my app directory.

```
-app/

--Acme/

---Users/

----User.php
```

I then removed the app/models directory

I added this to my composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/Acme/adminHelpers.php"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Acme/helpers.php",
        "app/Acme/adminHelpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\": "app/Acme"
    }
},
```

I also edited my app/auth.php file

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => 'app\Acme\Users\User',
```

I then ran `composer dump-autoload`

I'm now trying to install my Github repository using Laravel Forge but I keep getting this error:

```
...
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files



   [RuntimeException]                                                                              
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/models" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed `"app/models",` from `classmap` inside the composer.json file and it now works.